# facebook like button does not work properly

Tags: php, jquery, facebook

I have integrate all the code for facebook like button. But it does not work properly.

Suppose I am on my product detail page & I have given facebook like button to product image.
If user click on this like button count will be increment & this post will seen on user's profile page. My problem is that when I click on this like button count have increment proper but when I see on my facebook profile page it shares my domain link, title, description & image. Instead of that I want to show product URL, product title , product description & product image. I have done following code.

In the "head" tag I have written this code

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789012345"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Bliise"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="{$siteroot}/products/{$smarty.get.id1}/{$smarty.get.id2}/products"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="{$siteroot}/image.php?height=500&width=360&image=/product/{$prodDetails.product_image}"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="Bliise"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Bliise"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="Brand"/>
```

In the "body" tag I written this code

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

& this is the code for my facebook like button

```
<fb:like href="{$siteroot}/products/{$smarty.get.id1}/{$smarty.get.id2}/products" layout="button_count" style="float:left; width:70px; margin:12px 0px 0px 12px;" show_faces="false" width="240" height="40" action="like" colorscheme="light"></fb:like>
```

Comment: Have you cleared facebook's cache? http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: yes...but again there is same problem...it shares http://www.techmodi.com/demo/bliise/ instead of http://www.techmodi.com/demo/bliise/products/MTU=/MTQ=/products/

Comment: Try to fix the warnings output by the Facebook debug tool.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will helps you to find the problem

Also don't forget to add :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"
      xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```